# Caffe unable to find pthread

Tags: installation, pthreads

I am having an issue installing OpenCaffe. Make producing the following CMakeError file. I have installed all the dependencies as instructed. Python is anaconda 4.2.0

Should I use a different version of python or is there something I've missed?

```
Determining if the pthread_create exist failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/mlogin/temporal-segment-networks/lib/caffe-action/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_1d0f6/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_1d0f6.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_1d0f6.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/mlogin/temporal-segment-networks/lib/caffe-action/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_1d0f6.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o
/usr/bin/cc     -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_1d0f6.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o   -c /home/mlogin/temporal-segment-networks/lib/caffe-action/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c
Linking C executable cmTC_1d0f6
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_1d0f6.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc       CMakeFiles/cmTC_1d0f6.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o  -o cmTC_1d0f6 -rdynamic 
CMakeFiles/cmTC_1d0f6.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o: In function `main':
CheckSymbolExists.c:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/cmTC_1d0f6.dir/build.make:97: recipe for target 'cmTC_1d0f6' failed
make[1]: *** [cmTC_1d0f6] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/mlogin/temporal-segment-networks/lib/caffe-action/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Makefile:126: recipe for target 'cmTC_1d0f6/fast' failed
make: *** [cmTC_1d0f6/fast] Error 2

File /home/mlogin/temporal-segment-networks/lib/caffe-action/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c:
/* */
#include <pthread.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  (void)argv;
#ifndef pthread_create
  return ((int*)(&pthread_create))[argc];
#else
  (void)argc;
  return 0;
#endif
}

Determining if the function pthread_create exists in the pthreads failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/mlogin/temporal-segment-networks/lib/caffe-action/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_9f6ec/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_9f6ec.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_9f6ec.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/mlogin/temporal-segment-networks/lib/caffe-action/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_9f6ec.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o
/usr/bin/cc    -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_9f6ec.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o   -c /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/CheckFunctionExists.c
Linking C executable cmTC_9f6ec
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_9f6ec.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create    CMakeFiles/cmTC_9f6ec.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o  -o cmTC_9f6ec -rdynamic -lpthreads 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthreads
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/cmTC_9f6ec.dir/build.make:97: recipe for target 'cmTC_9f6ec' failed
make[1]: *** [cmTC_9f6ec] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/mlogin/temporal-segment-networks/lib/caffe-action/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Makefile:126: recipe for target 'cmTC_9f6ec/fast' failed
make: *** [cmTC_9f6ec/fast] Error 2
```

This is the output of the console (repeated a number of times for different targets)

```
CMake Error at cuda_compile_generated_threshold_layer.cu.o.cmake:207 (message):
  Error generating
  /home/mlogin/temporal-segment-networks/lib/caffe-action/build/src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/layers/./cuda_compile_generated_threshold_layer.cu.o


    src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/build.make:56765: recipe for target 'src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/layers/cuda_compile_generated_threshold_layer.cu.o' failed
    make[2]: *** [src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/layers/cuda_compile_generated_threshold_layer.cu.o] Error 1
    make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
    cc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
    Please submit a full bug report,
    with preprocessed source if appropriate.
    See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs> for instructions.
    CMake Error at cuda_compile_generated_roi_pooling_layer.cu.o.cmake:207 (message):
      Error generating
      /home/mlogin/temporal-segment-networks/lib/caffe-action/build/src/caffe/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/layers/./cuda_compile_generated_roi_pooling_layer.cu.o
```